# Backbone routes with optional '/'s and query parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, backbone-routing

Would like to set up a backbone route that matches a url that looks like this an all of its "intuitive" derivatives"

```
Base format: http://www.domain.com/PageName/:argument
Example:     http://www.domain.com/PageName/1234567890
```

The "intuitive" derivatives, in my opinion would be all of these urls:

```
Base url:                       http://www.domain.com/PageName/1234567890
With tailing slash:             http://www.domain.com/PageName/1234567890/
Base url with query params:     http://www.domain.com/PageName/1234567890?x=1
Tailing slash and query params: http://www.domain.com/PageName/1234567890/?x=1
```

The problem is that the backbone routes are getting super ugly:

```
routes:{    
    "PageName/:argument":           "main",
    "PageName/:argument/":          "main",
    "PageName/:argument/?:params":  "main",
    "PageName/:argument?:params":   "main"
}
```

I feel like this route should be able to be expressed in one line instead of 4 lines. Also, I don't need to be sending the url parameters through as an argument, I just wasn't able to get it to work without doing that.

How can I be specifying this route better?

Also, am I approaching this problem incorrectly? I feel like the fact that I had this problem to begin with may have to do with a more fundamental misunderstanding of the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`.route()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-route) and regex? if you want to have optional route elements, regex is probably the way to go. It means defining your routes in `.initialize()` instead of the `routes` hash, but it would solve your problem and involve less code.

I haven't tested this, but I think it would look like:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.route(/PageName\/([^\/\?]+)\/?\??(.*)/, "main");
}
```

(Testing the regex exposes one small issue here: You'll get an empty string for the params argument, not `undefined`. But that's probably not an issue for you.)

Comment: Yeah, this is probably what I should be doing.  Thanks so much!

Comment: how do you extract the query string in this example so you can pass it on?

Comment: From the docs: "Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback." So the two parenthetical patterns should be passed to the `main` handler.